# How do I remove jQuery validation from a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin to validate a form, and I'd like to remove the validation and submit the form if a certain link is clicked.

I am submitting form with javascript like `jQuery('form#listing').submit()`, so I must remove the validation rules/function with javascript.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried things like `jQuery('form#listing').validate({});` and `jQuery('form#listing').validate = null`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Trigger the DOM submit method to skip the validation:

```
$("#listing")[0].submit();
```

Comment: Indeed, that is a great tip, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This tip doesn't work instead of removing jquery validation it submit form

Comment: is [0] an array element from the form? can i use like [0,1,3] to disable these nodes?

Answer (score 36):

You can remove events of nodes with [unbind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind#typefn):

```
jQuery('form#listing').unbind('submit'); // remove all submit handlers of the form
```

What you are probably looking for is that the validation plugin can also unassign itself from the submit event:

```
jQuery('form#listing').validate({
   onsubmit : false
});
```

For both of these you should be able to follow up with a call to `.submit()` to submit the form:

```
jQuery('form#listing').unbind('submit').submit();
```

Comment: Only the unbind method worked for me. Using jQuery 1.3.2 and Validate 1.5.5

Answer (score 24):

```
var form = $('#my_form_id').get(0);
$.removeData(form,'validator');
```

Is really working.

Comment: After hacking around on this, the above needs to $(form).removeData('validator');

Comment: After this command I called again $("form").validate(GetSettings()); Inside GetSettings I only return {...,groups: GetValidationGroups(),...} which allowed me to dynamically change validation groups.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the public "rules" function in this way:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('remove');
});
```

That's what I'm using ;)

Comment: This worked pretty well for me.  I needed to remove rules that were already applied and then apply a smaller subset of rules.  In my case I have a Submit button (which enforces more required fields) and a Save button (which only enforces data format).  After submit, I get all sorts of required field validation errors, then I can do a save if there are no data format errors.  if there are some validation errors on save it will, unfortunately, show the required field validation errors too, but this is close enough for me.  I tried some of the other examples here to get rid of that without luck.

Comment: Yup.  I was in the same scenario as @KirkLiemohn: Multiple submit buttons with server side code that needs to know which was pressed.  Calling `.submit()` to submit the form would have obliterated that data, and your way was the only one that worked for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can add a css class of cancel to an element (button, input)  so that it skips the validation

Comment: I am submitting the form with javascript, so unfortunately that won't work.

Comment: Luckily I am not doing anything complicated so this worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: also can be used the html5 attribute formnovalidate on the submit element

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work for me now:

```
var form = $('#my_form_id').get(0);
$(form).removeData('validate');
```

Comment: meh.
Now i'm using the method mentioned by Jorn above. I can use this when I want to bypass validation:
<pre>
 bypassValidator = function(){
  $("#btn-submit").bind('click', function(){
   $('#myForm')[0].submit();                           
  });
 }
</pre>

Comment: your approach here solved a slightly different problem for me. I am dynamically loading in different forms via Ajax and if the field name was the same the existing validation would apply to it unless I first ran the code above.

Answer (score 7):

I have found none of the other ways helpful if you wanted to toggle on/off your forms validation (e.g. different validation for payment types...)

What I have had to do (this is not an nice fix but it does work)

Set up your validation:

```
jQuery('#form').validate();
```

Disabling the form:

```
jQuery('#form').validate().currentForm = '';
```

Enabling the form again:

```
jQuery('#form').validate().currentForm = jQuery('#form')[0];
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me out today. I had a form that I was submitting with ajax *and then clearing all inputs* so it could be used again - this triggered the validator to throw error messages up as if the user had deleted all required info. I use this on submit before clearing the form to avoid spamming the user with 'this field is required' messages :)

Comment: Works for after trying 6 other solutions. Why the jQ Validate is so unpredictable?

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#formName").validate().settings.ignore = "*";
```

Refer : https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/725

Answer (score 2):

I recently upgraded to 1.5.5 of Jörn's validator script and the removeValidator function has been deprecated.

```
...
jQuery.extend(
          jQuery.fn, 
          {
          removeValidator: function(){
              this.unbind();
              jQuery.removeData(this[0], 'validator'); 
          }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

For all the tags input of form:

```
$('#myform').validate().settings.ignore = '.valid';
$('input').addClass('valid');
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

in 2022

the answers above do not work now for me,

So I've written this js method, this would remove the jquery validation correctly

```
function RemoveJQVRule(rulename, inputname) {
   $(`[name="${inputname}"]`).rules('remove', rulename);
   $(`[name="${inputname}"]`).removeAttr(`data-val-${rulename}`);

   // message span element
   $(`#${inputname.replace(/\./img, '_')}-error`).html("");
   $(`[data-valmsg-for="${inputname}"]`).html("");
}
```

Examples:

```
    RemoveJQVRule('required', 'Shipper.Contact.NationalId');
    RemoveJQVRule('maxlength-max', 'SomeInputName');
    RemoveJQVRule('regex', 'SomeInputName');
```

Note:-
if it does not work you may need to edit it a little bit (the css selectors)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The validation lib now [provides](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/) a method to completely remove the configuration from the form.

Official example:

```
/*
 * On SPA page start.
 */
var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
 
/*
 * Just before SPA page's navigation away.
 */
validator.destroy();
 
/*
 * After this point the #myForm form is back to its original boring state.
 */
```