# jQuery turn off form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im using the bog standard form validation plugin. I have two radio buttons 'yes' 'no' and what im trying to do is set validation if a radio 'yes' is checked... Which works, but i need to then turn off validation if the 'no' radio is selected.  Im trying the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.cbyes').click(function() 
        {
            $('.hiddenDiv').show('slow');
            $("#regForm").validate();
        });
        $('.cbno').click(function() {
            $('.hiddenDiv').hide('slow');
            $('#regForm')[0].reset();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Old question, but for whoever is still looking, have a look here: [jQuery validate - set conditional rules based on user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543354/jquery-validate-set-conditional-rules-based-on-user-selection)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming there's no practical way to "turn off" validation once it's been applied to a form, can you use the validate method, but set it ignore everything in the form?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.cbyes').click(function() 
    {
        $('.hiddenDiv').show('slow');
        $("#regForm").validate();
    });
    $('.cbno').click(function() {
        $('.hiddenDiv').hide('slow');
        $('#regForm')[0].reset();
        $('#regForm').validate({
            ignore: "#regForm *"
        });
    });
});
```

This example uses a dumb universal selector that should be replaced with something more appropriate for your particular form.

Comment: If you want to submit the form and skip validation, the plugin's author has the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363268/how-do-remove-jquery-validation-from-a-form/1055371#1055371

Comment: Note to the reader:  This answer does not work with the latest version  of the plugin.  http://jsfiddle.net/tcZT4/

Comment: thank you most most kindly for the solution. It's just saved my day.