# jQuery: unbind All Event then do handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-events

I have ID name `#submit` and because of jQuery Plugin [Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) it attached more than 1 Javascript event (`click`,`focusin`,`focusout`,`keyup`,`submit`).

Now how do `unbind` all of that event and do the handler?

---

Normally if we want to unbind all, we will do like this:

```
$('#submit').unbind();
```

For unbind 1 event and do the handler, example `click`:

```
$('#submit').unbind('click', function() {
    // Do Handler
});
```

Comment: @adam: do whatever handler we want, example `alert('yes success')`

Comment: See my answer below for what I think is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so your issue is that unbind doesn't have a callback method on its signature.  If you want to rebind a new event to the button, do this:

```
$('#submit').unbind('click').click(function() {
    // Execute this function on click and no other click methods.
});
```

If you simply want to execute something after the unbinding as you seem to be attempting, then just put it on the next line.

Comment: thank you this is the right answer. i also a minute ago found this answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363268/how-do-i-remove-jquery-validation-from-a-form