# MVC 3 - AutoPostback with CauseValidation=false Behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, autopostback

I'm familiar with the method of submitting a form via a change event like  or a checkbox's check event.  Most articles explain how to find the first form using jQuery and invoke it's submit() method.  However, I wish to submit the form but not cause validation so the back-end can perform other actions.  In my case, I have a dropdown that a users changes.  Depending on the value, the back-end adds/removes certain controls.  The issue I'm runing into is that the validation prevents the form from submitting.

Q: **How do I submit the form so it does not perform client-side validation?**

Comment: solution:

$('form')[0].submit(); // invokes the DOM submit bypassing validation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the validation just before the form is submitted - check out the answers here [How do I remove jQuery validation from a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363268/how-do-i-remove-jquery-validation-from-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just turn the validation off by calling @Html.EnableClientValidation(false)

Comment: slfan,

This is interesting and I'll keep it in mind.  However, in my case I want validation to stay enabled the whole time except when a dropdown list's change event fires.  Using this method would proclude the validation on button submit.