# Disable jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby, jquery-validate, watir-webdriver

I'm completing a form using Web driver and need to bypass two form fields by using `browser.execute_script()` to insert a hidden form field into the DOM.

However I also need to disable existing validation methods in order to submit the form. The form uses jQuery Validate. Can anybody advise how to disable part or all of jQuery Validate?

I tried using the following, but I get the error `TypeError: d is undefined`

```
b.execute_script('
    $("firstMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
    $("secondMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
')
```

Where `firstMemorableCharacter` is the name of the form field which has attached validation rules.

The validation is set up using jQuery Validate as follows:

```
with($.validator) {
    addMethod(...);

setDefaults({
    ....
    messages: { },
    rules: {
            firstMemorableCharacter: {
                radioHasValue: true
            },
            secondMemorableCharacter: {
                radioHasValue: true
            }
    }
});
```

(The rules shown above are the ones that I need to disable.)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Following this post, [How do I remove jQuery validation from a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363268/how-do-i-remove-jquery-validation-from-a-form) , I tried submitting the form using the HTML DOM (bypassing jQuery) using `$("#form-id")[0].submit();`. However, this does not work - It seems there is some additional JavaScript within jQuery that needs to be executed in order for the form to submit properly.

Therefore I need a way of specifically disabling just these two rules within jQuery Validate, rather than disabling the whole of jQuery or jQuery Validate.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to complete the form normally (ie like a regular user) rather than hacking the page?

Comment: @JustinKo The problem is that its impossible to complete one of the fields normally, because it is a custom dropbox box element. If I change the element (in this case, the input radio element), I get the error that Im trying to access an HTML element that is not visible. SO I figured it would be easier to just insert a hidden form field.

Comment: The HTML for the element is like this:

    <div>
      <div class="option">
        <input id="firstMemorableCharacter1" class="" type="radio" value="a" name="firstMemorableCharacter">
        <label>
          <span>a</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
      .....
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: Your two jQuery selectors contain syntax errors.

Comment: @Imme22009 instead of putting that html in a comment, edit your question and put the info there where it can be properly formatted

Comment: Do you maybe need to simulate some event or action (like a mouseover, focus, hover, or onchange) to make the control visible?   If the user can manipulate it, there must be a way for it to become visible. Tell us more about this custom dropbox thing, most of those are not that hard to figure out, and if you happen to know the particular flavor (of jquery or whatever) of control there is often a demo page that can be used to develop simple sample code for how to work the control.   Also can you please include the version of watir-webdriver you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody advise how to disable part or all of JQuery Validator?

Once initialized, you cannot disable any part of it.  However, you can dynamically manipulate the rules using [the `.rules()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) as you've already guessed.

Just make sure the  `.rules()` method is called sometime *after* `.validate()` or it will fail.

**See this simple DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qdjMS/**

---

There is a syntax error in your code below.

```
$("firstMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
$("secondMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
```

Notice that your two jQuery selectors are meaningless.

If you're trying to target an `id`, then you'll need a `#` in front...

```
$("#firstMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
$("#secondMemorableCharacter").rules("remove");
```

From your comments, I also noticed that your element contains `id="firstMemorableCharacter1"`, so you also need to spell the `id` exactly the same...

```
$("#firstMemorableCharacter1").rules("remove");
```

Otherwise, you could just target them by `name` as also shown [in my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdjMS/)...

```
$("[name='firstMemorableCharacter']").rules("remove");
$("[name='secondMemorableCharacter']").rules("remove");
```

Comment: I'm not a giant fan of a brute force workaround like this, I'd rather fill out the form more organically.  IOW I think this is the wrong question for them to be asking. But that said, kudos for a well done answer that addresses what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden, I agree and I'm not really sure what the OP is ultimately trying to achieve with all this.

Comment: Perfect -thanks very much for the answer. I went with the rules("remove") and name targeting in the end - works great.