# Validate Form preventing form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I am using asp.net MVC 5 and trying to validate form on submission. everything works fine until i added the below line of code to validate form using ajax call.

```
    $('#signupform').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ type: "WhatsNew", code: $('#PrimaryCode').val() }),
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckCode", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response == 'success') {

                alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
        return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
    }
});
```

the above code simply blocking the submission of form.

Comment: Are you using the `unobtrusive-validation` script?  If so, it already calls the `.validate()` method, so you cannot call it again... it's just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You prevented submission by `return false;` in order to ajax-validate the form, but the form is not submitted after successful validation.

Add a form submit trigger inside `.done()`;

```
if (response == 'success') {    
    //  since validation is success, submit form here (e.g. YourForm.submit())
}
```

Comment: I tried by placing $('#signupform').submit();  inside the success block but still no form submission occur.

Answer (score 0):

Possible walk through:

- Before submitting the form inside .done(); make sure you remove/unbind validate from you form.
- Follow this link: [click here for another couple of ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363268/how-do-i-remove-jquery-validation-from-a-form)